# Flowtype not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use flowtype for responsive text, but it is not working? The file flowtype.js is in the same folder as my index files. Here are my body and head tags:

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="flowtype.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="zpics/maikalogo.ico" >
        <title>Website</title>
    <style>
        body {
              background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <script> 
            $('body').flowtype();
        </script>
<p>texttextmoretext</p>
</body>
```

Comment: **What exactly** isn't working?

Comment: Scripts should be declared inside `head`, not the `body`, which might be causing issues. However, we can't really solve the problem unless you explain what the problem is. As David asked, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Any conflict in your console please check

Answer (score 0):

You code in the position can't get $('body'). I suggest that you can modify your code as below:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').flowtype();
});
```

Comment: @C-link In the quenstion, script is put in the body, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

@andryuu87:

This code works, assuming that flowtype.js and jquery-1.11.0.js are both in the same folder as your html file from above:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="flowtype.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="zpics/maikalogo.ico" >
    <title>Website</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').flowtype();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>texttextmoretext</p>
</body>
</html>
```